# How to upload a file on server in c# in fast way

Tags: c#

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("request_uri_string");
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("path_to_my_file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)fileStream.Length))];   
int bytesRead = 1;
while (bytesRead != 0)
{
    bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} 
request.Close(); 
fileStream .Close();
```

Currently I am using above code.

Is there any other approach better (means FAST) than this?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure this is faster, but a lot more readable:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, localFileName);
}
```

EDIT:

Since `WebClient` is `IDisposable`, it should be properly disposed (I added `using`).

MSDN says:

> This method uses the `RETR` command to download an FTP resource. For an
>   HTTP resource, the `GET` method is used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the methods for WebClient:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekfaaeay.aspx

You can determine whether you want to do Async, or just regular. There are a handful of exposed methods for DownloadFile for both URI and regular string paths.